# Issue with textfield's rightView Button. Not working UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing for me

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am working with search bar with UITableview. For searching a text i am using textField and adding setting it in tableView's contentInset. For clearing text i am using rightView button.
Here i am getting weird issue that while editing text i am not able to show that rightView button.

```
txtSearch.rightView =  [self overlayButtonRight];
txtSearch.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;


- (UIButton *)overlayButtonRight {
if (!overlayButtonRight) {
    overlayButtonRight = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] ;
    overlayButtonRight.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 25, 14);
    UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark_right_green.png"];
    if (overlayImage) {
        [overlayButtonRight setImage:overlayImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
return overlayButtonRight;
```

}

Here i have described how i have applied this button. Using this `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing` is not working for me.

One more thing this is working fine in ios 5 but not working in ios6.

Let me know if you have solution.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi there. Do you mean your custom `rightView` is not visible?

Comment: Clarify "not working". Does the button appear? You don't seem to add an action to the button so you won't get any events.

Comment: Yes...It comes while we start searching. but when will we add some character rightView disappears.

Comment: it is not related to action of button.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an iOS bug..

This is what I did..

In your Text Field Subclass

```
    -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(didEditting:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingChanged];

}

-(void) didStartTyping:(id)sender {
    if(self.text){
        self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    }else{
        self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    }
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder{
    BOOL ret = YES ;
    ret = [super becomeFirstResponder] ;
    if( ret & self.text.length]){
        self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    }else{
        self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    }

    return ret ;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    BOOL ret = YES ;
    ret = [super resignFirstResponder] ;
    if( ret )
        self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    return ret ;
}
```

I think I found similar solution somewhere when I was hit with the same issue. Can't find it again.